# Snapshot captured from a webcam video in matlab is appearing bluish in color

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am working to recognise objects on the basis of distance between particular pixels in different color spaces, but am having trouble capturing an image. I want to get a snap shot from the live video from webcam but when I get this it is appearing bluish as it is shown in the image below:

[image]

Code I am using to capture the image:

```
obj=videoinput('winvideo',1);
preview(obj); start(obj);
A=getsnapshot(obj);
```

The adapter I have is:

```
    in=imaqhwinfo(obj)

    in = 

                AdaptorName: 'winvideo'
                 DeviceName: 'Webcam-101'
                  MaxHeight: 120
                   MaxWidth: 160
             NativeDataType: 'uint8'
               TotalSources: 1
    VendorDriverDescription: 'Windows WDM Compatible Driver'
        VendorDriverVersion: 'DirectX 9.0'
```

Comment: 1. Does `preview(obj)` show you what you expect? 2. How are you displaying/saving A?

Comment: yes preview(obj) is showing excatly the clear rgb image. but when its snapshot is taken using getsnapshot(obj) then it is appearing bluish.

Comment: i am showing it using imshow(A).

Comment: How does it look using `imagesc`? Also you might want to read through: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/imaq/examples/working-with-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you haven't set a property that will make the video RGB
This will help;

```
 obj=videoinput('winvideo',1);
 set(obj,'ReturnedColorSpace', 'RGB');
 preview(obj); start(obj);
 A=getsnapshot(obj);
```

This will make the image stop being bluish

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line:

```
 obj.ReturnedColorspace = 'rgb';
```

So it becomes:

```
obj=videoinput('winvideo',1);
obj.ReturnedColorspace = 'rgb';
preview(obj); start(obj);
A=getsnapshot(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting clear images or snapshots you can use the print screen button on your keyboard and then you can paste it on paint or any image processing applications like photoshop and all.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!. How do you propose to push the `print screen` button programatically in Matlab?